# Interpolating a variable into a variable name in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, interpolation

I will be looping through code k times (where k = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). In each loop, I am creating a variable called "atomDistances". Obviously, the way I have it now, I only get the "atomDistances" variable from the last k iteration (k=5).

Is it possible for me to create a variable called "atomDistances_1, atomDistances_2, ..., atomDistances_5" in each iteration by interpolating the integer variable k (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) into the variable name atomDistances_k?

Having difficulty if this is possible in MatLab, as it does not seem to be available in a few other languages. Thank you!!!

Comment: Before I started using Matlab, I used to wish for this functionality in other languages.  Then when I tried it out in Matlab, I realized that there is almost always a better way to solve the problem. Especially when you realize that variable names exist for the programmer's sake, not the computer's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you suggest is possible using `eval` as follows:

```
eval(sprintf('atomDistances_%d = atomDistances;',k));
```

I would suggest against using this method though, as using `eval` is generally not best practise. Have you tried using a cell array instead? For instance:

```
atomDistances = cell(1,5);
for k=1:5
    atomDistances{k} = ...;
end
```

you can then access each loop result using `atomDistances{1}`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, MrAzzaman! 1) Why is eval not good practice? Is it safe in general? 2) I do not know if your second recommendation would work. It might be a problem, because atomDistances is a <1*392 double> data structure...

Comment: Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) for more information on why it's not always a good idea to use eval. The size of the data structure shouldn't matter, as a cell-array is basically just an array of matlab variables. It just means than instead of having atomDistances_1, atomDistances_2, you have atomDistances{1}, atomDistances{2}. Internally there is very little difference between the two.

Comment: +1 for explaining how to do it, *and then* explaining why NOT to do it.

Comment: Despite the need for `eval`, it also simply bad practice to use variable-names like that, even if you had them hardcoded without `eval`. List-datatypes exist in all programming languages, exactly to avoid the need for such ugly constructs. Last but not least: Using arrays/lists make progamming much more efficient since you'll have the benefit of being able to use things like `cellfun` and very comfortable indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Matlab can do this. Use `eval`. The loop below creates the five variables you've asked for.

```
for k=1:5
   eval(['atomDistances_' num2str(k) '=' num2str(k)]); 
end
```